# Filter with parents selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

help me please. I need to add a filter to the paint catalog.

I have a code like this on the page:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <input id="myInputDiv" type="text">
            <script>
                (function ($) {
                    $('#myInputDiv').on('keyup', function () {
                        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
                        $('#myDIV *').filter(function () {
                            $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);
                        });
                    });
                }(jQuery));
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="myDIV">
        <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-md-2 color-teaser">
            <div class="views-fields">
                <div class="views-field views-field-field-c-rgb-id">
                    <div class="color-teaser-display" style="background-color: #F6F3E6; color: #F6F3E6" role="img" alt="#F6F3E6"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="views-field views-field-title"> <span class="field-content">F300</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-md-2 color-teaser">
            <div class="views-fields">
                <div class="views-field views-field-field-c-rgb-id">
                    <div class="color-teaser-display" style="background-color: #F9EFD8; color: #F9EFD8" role="img" alt="#F9EFD8"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="views-field views-field-title"> <span class="field-content">G300</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As a result of the script I get this:

```
<div class="views-field views-field-title"> 
    <span class="field-content">F300</span>
</div>
```

But I need this:

```
<div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-md-2 color-teaser c-id-24958 views-row">
    <div class="views-fields">
        <div class="views-field views-field-field-c-rgb-id">
            <div class="color-teaser-display" style="background-color: #F6F3E6; color: #F6F3E6" role="img" alt="#F6F3E6"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="views-field views-field-title"> <span class="field-content">F300</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I change the script to get the desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to filter on the `children` elements of `myDIV`:

```js
(function ($) {
  $('#myInputDiv').on('keyup', function () {
      var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
      $('#myDIV').children().filter(function () {
          $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);
      });
  });
}(jQuery));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <input id="myInputDiv" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="myDIV">
        <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-md-2 color-teaser">
            <div class="views-fields">
                <div class="views-field views-field-field-c-rgb-id">
                    <div class="color-teaser-display" style="background-color: #F6F3E6; color: #F6F3E6" role="img" alt="#F6F3E6"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="views-field views-field-title"> <span class="field-content">F300</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-md-2 color-teaser">
            <div class="views-fields">
                <div class="views-field views-field-field-c-rgb-id">
                    <div class="color-teaser-display" style="background-color: #F9EFD8; color: #F9EFD8" role="img" alt="#F9EFD8"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="views-field views-field-title"> <span class="field-content">G300</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of `$('#myDIV *')` use `$('#myDIV > div')` so you are only filtering the dive with col-4 in it

```js
(function ($) {
    $('#myInputDiv').on('keyup', function () {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $('#myDIV > div').filter(function () {
            $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);
        });
    });
}(jQuery));
```

```css
.color-teaser{
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <input id="myInputDiv" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="myDIV">
        <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-md-2 color-teaser">
            <div class="views-fields">
                <div class="views-field views-field-field-c-rgb-id">
                    <div class="color-teaser-display" style="background-color: #F6F3E6; color: #F6F3E6" role="img" alt="#F6F3E6"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="views-field views-field-title"> <span class="field-content">F300</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-md-2 color-teaser">
            <div class="views-fields">
                <div class="views-field views-field-field-c-rgb-id">
                    <div class="color-teaser-display" style="background-color: #F9EFD8; color: #F9EFD8" role="img" alt="#F9EFD8"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="views-field views-field-title"> <span class="field-content">G300</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```